# Issue making a Liferay Hook with Eclipse Liferay IDE - getting only empty project

Tags: plugins, liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I am using Eclipse Liferay IDE for making a hook to a Liferay native portlet. I mean a porlet that comes with default installation, eg. blogs, content management or similar.

I have done the steps like following:

> 1. Select `new Liferay Project`
> 2. Enter project name `MyHook`
> 3. Made configurations (found an SDK directory and Liferay Server instance for Runtime)
> 4. Selected Plugin type to `Hook`

My only option after that was `Finish` and I ended up having a project with certain structure without any *class* or *properties* file inside.

My problem is that I could only get an empty project and don't know how to make the modifications to the files of Liferay because no Liferay originated package names can be found if I make a new class file and try to start typing `com.Liferay.` or `org.Liferay.` Because this is a Liferay Hook project, I suppose some *Liferay* originating tips should normally pop up for my selection, but I didn't see any.

What I am making wrong? What I am missing? Should I know the filenames by myself or is there a trick somewhere to tell the IDE to give me some help?

I use Liferay 6.0 and my IDE version is 6.0.5. At least in my eyes they should match together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IDE you first create a "Liferay Hook Project". This is indeed an empty project. Then you create a Hook, select the Hook project to create it in. You can do the second step manually, but there's a wizard helping you to do this. This might be what you've been missing

Comment: Yes this was the case. The project type on the first try was somehow `Java` instead of `Liferay` and creating Hook was disabled on the menus. Creating one with correct type solved the problem I was able to follow the way you told here.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same steps again and it worked! Somehow at first time I managed to do a Java project although the project should be interpreted as a Liferay project.

Maybe the IDE is not 100% working always. Whoever knows.

Comment: My first try had a very long name also. Probably there is a limit on the name lenght.